# blocking url if record not active

Tags: django

I have Business model that has an active field that defaults to False. This field is set to True when the user has submitted a payment.

The business model has a "profile" page. I was wondering if there is any way of not allowing access to that profile page if the `active` field is not set to True.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('listings.views',
    # other patterns here...
    url(r'^profile/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$', 'business_profile', name="business_profile"),
    # other urls here...
)
```

Should I just check this field in the `view.business_profile` method? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One better way *might* be to set the `business_profile` view to [return a 404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) in case the 'business model' instance has `active=False`.